# Call to lme4 extremely slow when run from rmarkdown

Tags: knitr, lme4

I am applying the `lmer()` function from the lme4 package to a series of rows in a matrix. The calculations take a few minutes.

I have included precisely the same code in an Rmarkdown document. When I process the document with `rmarkdown::render()`, the same bit of code takes an order of magnitude longer to execute (1 or 2 hours on my laptop).

Question: is the code in knitr executed in a different way then when run in the console? Is there a possible interaction between knitr and lme4 that would slow down the execution of lme4 model optimization code?